# Is your fate sealed in the Preserved Tablet?

Tags: jannah, jahannam, akhirah, qadar

In these verses of the Qur'an, they imply that our fate is pre-destined.

> He is the Knower of the unseen. Not an atom's weight escapes Him, be it in the heavens or the earth, nor what is smaller than that or larger. All are but in a clear Record. 34:3

> With Him are the keys to the unseen. None knows them except Him. He knows what is on land and in the sea. No leaf falls without Him knowing thereof, nor is there a grain in the darkness of the earth, nor anything wet or dry that is not recorded in a clear Book. 6:59

> We have kept count of everything in a Record. 78:29

> No disaster falls in the land, or to yourselves that is not already contained in a Record before
> We bring it into existence. This is easy for God. 57:22

This makes me think that I am determined to go to either Heaven or Hell, without any free will. If Allah (AZZAWAJAL) records everything in a tablet, then we cannot change it. Is this view correct, or false?

Comment: (Human can have nothing except what he strives for.) Quran (53:39)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's written in Lauhul Mahfudz. Regarding this worldly life, if we are destined to do something then we automatically will get in the situation, and intend to do it, and it's easy to do it. Regarding the afterlife, too. If we are destined to be in paradise then we'll automatically do the deeds of people of paradise. There's many hadith about it. For example:

[Bukhari 6605](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6605)
[Bukhari 1362](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:1362)
[Bukhari 6596](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6596)
[Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/urn/722780)
[Abu Dawud 4709](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:4709)
[Muslim 2650](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2650)
[Muslim 2647](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2647a)
[Muslim 2647c](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2647c)
[Bukhari 3208](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3208)
[Bukhari 3332](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3332)
[Bukhari 6607](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6607)
[Abi Dawud 4612](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:4612)
etc

However, that doesn't mean we should rely on our destiny. We should do something called ikhtiar (which means trying).

> "Verily, God does not change men's condition unless they change their
> inner selves"
>
> Ar-Ra'ad verse 11

Try to think positive, that Allah has destined you to do the deeds of people of the paradise, Insha Allah.
Wallahu a'lam.

Comment: Ik this is someone else’s post but does this mean the duaas made in shab e barat change what is written for us or is this something that cannot be answered

Comment: "Your Lord says, ‘Call on Me and I will answer you; those who are too proud to serve Me will enter Hell humiliated.'" Qur'an 40:60 (translated by Muhammad Abdel Haleem). Shaykh al-Islam Ibn Taymiyah said in Majmoo’ al-Fataawa (8/287): One of them said: Du’aa’ is nothing more than pure worship, because what is decreed will happen, whether one says du’aa’ or not. It was said to him: (if) Allaah has made du’aa’ a means of attaining the desired outcome that has been decreed, so how can it happen without du’aa’?! End quote. Wallahu a'lam

Comment: This does not really ask the question, however. Did Allah (SWT) destine us to go to either Jannah or Jahannam or is it in our Free Will, but he already knows the answer and writes it down?

Comment: We have free will from our perspective, but it's impossible to be against God's wills. Allah SWT destine us to go to either Jannah or Naar (hell). Even if we do bad deeds, if we are destined to go to Jannah then it's easy for us to do the deeds of people of the paradise as our closing deeds and thus we go to Jannah, and vice versa (Bukhari 3208, 3332, 6607) (Hadith in the answer). However, do not depend on our destiny. (Our Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ) had told us to not depend on our destiny, as mentioned in the hadith above). Allah SWT knows what we will do in our lifetime. Wallahu a'lam